# 413 Payload Too Large in ionic api calling

Tags: ionic-framework, laravel-api

I'm new to ionic. I am trying to make app in ionic and api's in laravel. I am trying to send base64 in body but it's giving me 413 Payload Too Large. If i don't send base64 then it's retuning 201 created

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/413 :

> The HTTP 413 Payload Too Large response status code indicates that the
> request entity is larger than limits defined by server

So this issue is not related to your Ionic application, neither to the laravel API. Your server may have file upload size limits. By default the max size is 2MB.

You can edit this value by editing your php.ini :

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```